# ContextMenu attribute not working for me?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
[ContextMenu("Fill the pull")]
public void FillThePull(int count)
{

}
```

I selected object with my script, but I don`t finding my func in menu.
[image]

Comment: Try removing the parameter `int count`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I forgot that I can't use the parameters in context menu functions.

```
[ContextMenu("Fill the pull")]
public void FillThePull()
{

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).